# Jquery select background color for alt tag caption from array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am using the code below to select background colors for slideshow captions that are coming from the alt tag of an img. Currently the array values are selected randomly using Math.random. I want to select them in order of how they are input into the array instead. Help would be much appreciated.

```
function captionUpdate() {
                var nextCaption = $('#'+uniqueId).find('.ss-slide:eq(-2) img').prop('alt');
                var bgColorArray = ['red','yellow','green'],
    selectBG = bgColorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgColorArray.length)];

                //var count = 1;
                if (!nextCaption) {
                    $('#'+uniqueId).find(".ss-caption").css('opacity','0');

                } else {
                    $('#'+uniqueId).find(".ss-caption").css('opacity','1').html(nextCaption);
                    $('.ss-caption').css('background-color', selectBG);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should maintain a global bgColorIndex variable and advance it each time you show the next caption:

Place this globally before your caption:

```
var bgColorIndex = 0;
```

Change your select BG in the following way:

```
selectBG = bgColorArray[(bgColorIndex++) % bgColorArray.length];
```